# How to remove empty objects from Json Array

Tags: java, android, json

So the json is something like it,

```
"stores": [
{
"amazon": []
},
{
"flipkart": {
"product_store": "Flipkart",
"product_store_logo": "http://images-api.datayuge.in/image/ZmxpcGthcnRfc3RvcmUucG5n.png",
"product_store_url": "https://price-api.datayuge.com/redirect?id=aHR0cHM6Ly9kbC5mbGlwa2FydC5jb20vZGwvbWktYTEtYmxhY2stNjQtZ2IvcC9pdG1leDl3eHh6M2FtamF0P3BpZD1NT0JFWDlXWFVTWlZZSEVUJmFmZmlkPWFydW5iYWJ1bA",
"product_price": "14999",
"product_offer": "",
"product_color": "",
"product_delivery": "3-4",
"product_delivery_cost": "0",
"is_emi": "1",
"is_cod": "1",
"return_time": "10 Days"
}
},
{
"snapdeal": []
}
]
```

So the non empty object like flipkart is a JsonObject but all other empty objects are array. So I am so confused about how to remove them.

```
JSONArray store_array = product_details_json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("stores");
                    for (int i = 0; i<store_array.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject store = store_array.getJSONObject(i);

                        if (!store.getJSONObject(store.keys().next()).has("product_store")){
                            store_array.remove(i);
                        }else {
                            Log.i("Size :",store_array.length()+"");

                        }
                    }
```

But that's not working. I know I am doing this all wrong. Because it has both array and objects so i get the following error

```
Value [] at amazon of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Need Help!

Comment: _"But that's not working."_ -- What does that mean? Does it crash? Produce incorrect results? Please provide details of what you expect and what actually happens.

Comment: @TedHopp Edited With The Error..

Comment: why do you want to remove those values?

Comment: Well, you have a heterogeneous structure. The keys `"amazon"` and `"snapdeal"` have empty arrays as values, while `"flipkart"` has an object as a value. You'll have to either modify your JSON to be homogeneous (e.g., all keys map to objects) or modify your code to deal with the possibility that each key may map to an array or an object.

Comment: Trying to show the available stores in a recyclerview @diegoveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems with your code:

1. Your JSON structure for `"stores"` is heterogeneous — some elements have a key that maps to an array and some to an object. That's the immediate cause of the error you are seeing. You can either modify your JSON so everything key maps to an object or code defensively.
2. When you remove an entry, all subsequent entries move up one space, but since you then increment the loop index `i`, you skip the entry that just moved into the index you just removed. The easiest way to deal with that is to iterate through `store_array` in reverse order.

Putting this all together (and assuming you aren't going to change your JSON structure), something like the following (untested) should work:

```
JSONArray store_array = product_details_json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("stores");

for (int i = store_array.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    JSONObject store = store_array.getJSONObject(i);
    Object storeData = store.get(store.keys().next());
    boolean isValidStore = storeData instanceof JSONObject
            && ((JSONObject) storeData).has("product_store");
    if (!isValidStore) {
        store_array.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for this answer. I was stuck in this problem from 2 hours. Never used instanceOf in any of my work(noob). So this thing never came to my mind. Again Thank you....